# Powershell script restarts Dropbox but without the icon in system tray

Tags: powershell, dropbox, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Dropbox on Windows Server 2012 R12 Standard. As far as I know Dropbox is not officially supported but seems to work most of the time.

As background, Dropbox sometimes gets stuck "syncing" without syncing any data. So I wrote a powershell script to detect when there is a problem, connected it to Task Scheduler to run every 30 minutes, and to restart Dropbox if necessary.

The following powershell script restarts dropbox nicely.

```
Stop-Process -processname Dropbox
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Dropbox\Client\Dropbox.exe' /home
```

The powershell script is executed via Task Scheduler with the following settings:

**Program/Script**: `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe"`

**Add arguments**: `-NoProfile -Executionpolicy bypass -file  "C:\Scheduled Tasks\checkDropboxHealth.ps1"`

Dropbox restarts and starts synchronizing, whether the script is run via the Powershell ISE or whether it is run via Task Scheduler. The only difference is that when it is run via Task Scheduler, dropbox runs without the icon in the system tray. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you mean the taskbar or the system tray? https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-tray-menu-bar. Are you sure Dropbox is launching? If you run your script as a .ps1, does it launch as you expect? Your scheduled task's action should be configured with program=Powershell.exe with arguments `-File C:\path\Dropbox.ps1`.

Comment: Thanks @root... I have updated my question based on your points... I did not realize before that the problem is with how the script execution specifically via Task Scheduler, so I think we are half-way to a solution!